# syntax highlighting not workign for ".txt" file

Tags: vim

**Context**: I want to create `;` delimeted `.txt` file, which also contains few `HTML` tags. This file i later use to upload to `Anki` tool for later study. I wanted `syntax` highlighting and few abbreviations to input fast.

**Issue 1**: I'm setting few abbreviations & syntax in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/text.vim` file. But, when i open `*.txt` file to edit, I don't see the abbreviations or syntax working. But when i see `:scriptnames` i see file(`...text.vim`) has loaded. But `:set filetype?` prints `filetype=text`.

I assume since i put my desired behavior in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/text.vim` i'm expecting it to take affect whenever i open `.txt` file. I can manually run `:so ~/.vim/after/ftplugin/text.vim` everytime i open `.txt` file which is not efficient.

What am I doing wrong here, kindly help.

Content of `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/text.vim` is as below.

```
" Abbreviations to insert HTML tags for Anki Notes
iab it      <i></i><Left><Left><Left><Left>
iab bd      <b></b><Left><Left><Left><Left>
iab br      <br>
iab cd      <code></code><Left><Left><Left><Left><Left><Left><Left>

" ordered & unordered list
iab ol      <ol></ol><Left><Left><Left><Left><Left>
iab ul      <ul></ul><Left><Left><Left><Left><Left>
" list item within 
iab li      <li></li><Left><Left><Left><Left><Left>
iab dt      <detail><summary>Read more</summary><p></p></details><Left><Left><Left><Left><Left><Left><Left><Left><Left><Left><Left><Left><Left><Left>

" retain tab as is
set noexpandtab 
set syntax=html
```

Following is my output of `:scriptnames`. Line #27 shows file has loaded

```
  2: /usr/share/vim/vim82/debian.vim
  3: /usr/share/vim/vim82/syntax/syntax.vim
  4: /usr/share/vim/vim82/syntax/synload.vim
  5: /usr/share/vim/vim82/syntax/syncolor.vim
  6: /usr/share/vim/vim82/filetype.vim
  7: ~/.vim/vimrc
  8: /usr/share/vim/vim82/defaults.vim
  9: /usr/share/vim/vim82/ftplugin.vim
 10: /usr/share/vim/vim82/indent.vim
 11: /usr/share/vim/vim82/syntax/nosyntax.vim
 12: /usr/share/vim/vim82/plugin/getscriptPlugin.vim
 13: /usr/share/vim/vim82/plugin/gzip.vim
 14: /usr/share/vim/vim82/plugin/logiPat.vim
 15: /usr/share/vim/vim82/plugin/manpager.vim
 16: /usr/share/vim/vim82/plugin/matchparen.vim
 17: /usr/share/vim/vim82/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim
 18: /usr/share/vim/vim82/plugin/rrhelper.vim
 19: /usr/share/vim/vim82/plugin/spellfile.vim
 20: /usr/share/vim/vim82/plugin/tarPlugin.vim
 21: /usr/share/vim/vim82/plugin/tohtml.vim
 22: /usr/share/vim/vim82/plugin/vimballPlugin.vim
 23: /usr/share/vim/vim82/plugin/zipPlugin.vim
 24: ~/.vim/pack/tpope/start/dispatch/plugin/dispatch.vim
 25: /usr/share/vim/vim82/scripts.vim
 26: /usr/share/vim/vim82/ftplugin/text.vim
 27: ~/mydotfiles/vim/after/ftplugin/text.vim
 28: /usr/share/vim/vim82/syntax/html.vim
 29: /usr/share/vim/vim82/syntax/javascript.vim
 30: /usr/share/vim/vim82/syntax/vb.vim
 31: /usr/share/vim/vim82/syntax/css.vim
```

Comment: Two problems => two questions.

Comment: @romainl, i've edited the question made sure it only one problem/question